# RAID array failure. False positive?

Tags: raid, raid-1, hardware-raid

**Background**:

I have 3 storage units in my PC:

- an SSD that contains my operating systems
- a 1TB hard-drive that is about 5 - 6 years old
- a 1TB hard-drive that is only a few months old

The 2 big harddrives make up a RAID1 array. This array is a "hardware" one, not a "software" one a.k.a. I set it up using an application on a bootable USB flash drive, not from within the operating system.

Also, my motherboard is ASRock 970 Extreme3 R2.0 (maybe it's relevant).

**The problem**:

This weekend I moved all the components to a new case. Everything worked great and there seemed to be no problems after the operation.

The status of the array is always checked when the computer first starts-up. This morning, I saw this:

[image: RAID error]

It's very possible that this error started to appear after I moved everything in the new case, though I'm not sure (it only stays on the screen for 2 seconds maximum, so I might have missed it). Also, from what I can remember, I went to the motherboard's BIOS immediately after "the big operation" and saw that all drives were there and being detected normally.

The interesting thing is that, if I do nothing, the system boots normally and I can see all the drives in my OS and everything just works normally...

OK, so I have 2 questions:

- Is one of my hard-drives really gone ? Isn't this failure a false-positive ? The timing is a little odd, I doubt that switching to another case is just a giant coincidence. My theory is that the motherboard requires that **HDDs that are part of a RAID array must remain connected to the same SATA ports**. Could this be true in my case ? (I know for a fact that I used DIFFERENT ports when I put the PC back together, due to wire-management issues)
- If one of the drives is indeed gone, how do I find out which ? Why doesn't the PC tell me **which drive** failed ? It's the most important thing and a MAJOR failure as far as UX / UI is concerned.

Thank you in advance :) .

PS: Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> just takes me to a blank screen, it probably needs that bootable USB flash drive that I used to create the array. I will try using it as soon as I get home and will update the question with what I find.

EDIT: The devices listed there have nothing to do with my array, which is odd: "HL-DT-ST..." is an optical drive and "KINGSTON SV3..." is the SSD.

Comment: Go into the RAID controller interface and check all the settings. You may need to get the controller to re-identify the disk and then run an integrity check to bring the disks back online together. Do you have a backup?

Comment: Ps. It looks like you're using a hardware controller - you shouldn't need the USB disk you used... Also;: are the disks actually connected properly and powered up?

Comment: @BigChris I don't really know where the RAID controller interface is (it's the first time I use RAID). Like I said in the question: Pressing Ctrl+F leads me to a blank screen...

Comment: @RaduMurzea 1. Install OS at SSD and add RAID driver. 2. Copy Information to another HDD. 3. You can experiment and build theories))

Comment: Go to your BIOS (according to the manual) where there is a RAID options screen for your motherboard, check that your hard disks are still identified...